# Will anyone help me debug "proto descriptor was previously loaded" from Google Ads API

Tags: php, laravel, grpc, google-ads-api, protobuf-c

I'm getting this error when running this code:

```
$googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient()->search($customerId, $query, $page_size);
```

ERROR message:
`proto descriptor was previously loaded (included in multiple metadata bundles?): google/ads/googleads/v5/enums/policy_topic_evidence_destination_not_working_dns_error_type.proto`

$googleAdsClient is an instance of `\Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V5\GoogleAdsClient`.

The `getGoogleAdsServiceClient` method comes from the `ServiceClientFactoryTrait` trait `/Google/Ads/GoogleAds/Lib/V5/ServiceClientFactoryTrait.php`

I'm running:

```
php 7.4.1
grpc module version => 1.34.0
protobuf version => 3.14.0
```

Additional libs installed via composer:

```
google/grpc-gcp                       0.1.5      gRPC GCP library for channel management
google/protobuf                       v3.13.0.1  proto library for PHP
googleads/google-ads-php              v5.0.0     Google Ads API client for PHP
grpc/grpc                             1.30.0     gRPC library for PHP
```

I don't know enough about descriptors or the protobuf library to understand this error. It just started happening a couple days ago and I don't think we made any changes that would effect this. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

EDIT: forgot to link to SDK https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php

EDIT: updated the following libs:

```
google/apiclient                     v2.9.1     Client library for Google APIs
google/apiclient-services            v0.161.0   Client library for Google APIs
google/auth                          v1.15.0    Google Auth Library for PHP
google/common-protos                 1.3        Google API Common Protos for PHP
google/gax                           1.7.0      Google API Core for PHP
google/grpc-gcp                      0.1.5      gRPC GCP library for channel management
google/protobuf                      v3.15.3    proto library for PHP
googleads/google-ads-php             v7.0.0     Google Ads API client for PHP
grpc/grpc                            1.35.0     gRPC library for PHP
google/protobuf                      v3.15.3    proto library for PHP
```

Comment: You may want to file an issue on the GitHub repo for the SDK in order to more quickly engage with its developers: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/issues. You're running an old version of `google-ads-php` (v5.0.0) currently v7.0.0 **but** beside trying to maintain currency this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: According to a developer on the googleads/google-ads-php lib this is a warning message. I guess I don't understand what the error/warning means "proto descriptor was previously loaded (included in multiple metadata bundles?)". Can anyone explain this?

Comment: `.proto` files contain protobuf definitions that are the sources used by the protobuf compiler (`protoc`) to generate language-specific (e.g. PHP) implementations. It's curious that the error message specifies a `.proto` file rather than the (in this case) PHP classes that it defines. It's possible that the `.proto` is used by several components of the Ads SDK. Protobufs  are often bundled with sources and so shared Protobufs could end up being duplicated. Still, an unusual message; I've not seen anything similar.

Comment: @DazWilkin concern I have is that this is an error saying that I have to many file descriptors open and I'm running out therefore throwing this error.

Comment: Perhaps include that error in your question? Everything helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue for me. I had the C implementation installed via `pecl install protobuf`. Sense I'm running my app in a docker container, every time I built a new image it would install the latest release of protobuf. Sense I started seeing this error around the 22nd of Feb I looked at the [protobuf builds](https://pecl.php.net/package/protobuf) and I see a build on the 20th of Feb for version 3.15.0 which coincides with a new build I ran on the 22nd.

To fix this I downgraded to version 3.14.0 via the `pecl install protobuf-3.14.0` command in my Dockerfile. This isn't a permanent fix as at some point I want to upgrade the package but I will have to wait for a version that deals with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was addressed in https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/issues/540 and fixed in protobuf version 3.18.0 ( https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.18.0 )

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because two library is your project are providing the proto descriptor for same file `policy_topic_evidence_destination_not_working_dns_error_type.proto`.
Looks like this issue was fixed in version v6 for google ads library [link](https://github.com/mechiru/googapis/pull/9)

Just update the libarry to v6 and above (latest is v7) and it should fix the problem
[Latest Release](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/releases)

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, I commented out the line

```
; extension=protobuf.so
```

in /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini and
in /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and error was gone, I hope this will be helpful for someone.